# python Queue, SimpleQueue, task_done

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

1. Do I have to call `task_done()` when I use `queue.Queue()`?
2. If I don't need task counting, should I use `queue.SimpleQueue` instead (for a better performance)?
   I am not sure if `SimpleQueue` is thread-safe? cause I see that the `put()` implementation does not acquire a lock?
3. As I seed in `Queue()` implementation, if I won't call task_done(), there is a counter which is incremented, and since my program is long running, not calling task_done() will cause some memory leak? because of counting up too high number.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have to call `task_done()` unless you use `Queue.join()` function.

> `Queue.join()` blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.

> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls `task_done()` to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it is complete. When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, `join()` unblocks.

2. Yes, you can use `queue.SimpleQueue` instead of `queue.Queue` as more light-weight version if you don't need the functionality of tracking (`task_done`, `join`). `SimpleQueue` is thread-safe and more, as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62223662/13782669)

> It handles reentrancy - it is safe to call `queue.SimpleQueue.put` in precarious situations where it might be interrupting other work in the same thread. For example, you can safely call it from `__del__` methods, `weakref` callbacks, or signal module signal handlers.

Note: At least this applies to its С implementation.

3. As I know, `queue.Queue` uses `int` as a counter for `put`. And the possibility that this counter will occupy too much memory is of more theoretical rather than practical, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Another thing `SimpleQueue` lacks is a size bound. If you need backpressure (and you do need backpresure with almost every queue), `SimpleQueue` will be a memory leak waiting to happen.