# Interprocess communication using asyncio?

Tags: python, async-await, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have a set of CPU-intensive processes that once in a while depend on each other to proceed. So something like

```
def run():
  while True:
    do stuff
    wake up some other process
    wait for some other process to wake me up
    do stuff
```

Within each process I'd like to use async, so that I can always have an instance of `run` running while others are waiting to be woken up. Looking at the `asyncio` docs, the only IPC option in the "High-level APIs" section that I see uses sockets. I'd much rather use a pipe, which it looks like I can perhaps do with the low-level API, but that documentation is chock full of warnings that if you're just writing an application then it's a mistake to be using it. Can someone weigh in on the idiomatic thing to do here? (And also, speed is an important factor, so if there's some less-idiomatic-but-more-performant thing I'd like to know about that option as well.)

Comment: Using asyncio your best option is probably to use sockets, as that's best-supported. You could use domain sockets to avoid the overhead of (local) TCP/IP. The only public async interface to pipes is by spawning a subprocess. But while you can communicate with a subprocess asynchronously, inside the subprocess there is no facility for async communication with the parent.

Comment: That's a shame. I'm particularly surprised there aren't async versions of the data structures in `multiprocessing`.

Comment: I think there's an `aiomultiprocessing`, but AFAIR it just uses a thread pool to run the real multiprocessing under the hood and present an "asynchronous" API on top. As multiprocessing itself starts a number of threads, you pay for the resources of both.

Comment: *Within each process I'd like to use xxx, so that I can always have an instance of run running while others are waiting to be woken up.*. I would replace xxx with mutex, lock, semaphore, or any other synchronization tool, but certainly not asyncio. Why do you thing asyncio to be the right tool here?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Each thread periodically blocks waiting for data from another process. I want that thread to wake up only when data is available. Doesn't `threading` use pre-emptive threads? This seems like it would lead to a lot of wasted cycles (not to mention the fact that the code would have to be written more carefully to explicitly manage the locks). Why do you say that `asyncio` is not the right thing to use here?

Comment: When you say *I want that thread to wake up only when data is available*, I see this as a hint that asyncio may not be the solution. You should give some more context about your processes or threads, where/how they find their input, and where/how they produce the output. Asyncio may be the best solution, but what you say does not clearly demonstrate it.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to mention the [aioprocessing](https://github.com/dano/aioprocessing/) library, as I successfully used it in one of my projects. It provides an anync interface to the `multiprocessing` primitives including IPC, such as `Process`, `Pipe`, `Lock`, `Queue` and etc.   It uses thread pool to do this:

```
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def coro_maker(func):
        def coro_func(self, *args, loop=None, **kwargs):
            return self.run_in_executor(
                getattr(self, func), *args, loop=loop, **kwargs
            )

        return coro_func
```

But to be honest, a lot depends on the problem being solved, on what tasks are being performed concurrently, since the intensive IPC itself within the async approach is less effective than the synchronous approach due to overhead of event loop, thread pool and etc. Sometimes it is better to make all IPC operations synchronous and put it all in a separate thread. Again, it all depends on the problem and the environment. Below is a benchmark that is far from comprehensive, but it can give an approximate picture of the problem that is being solved in it (intensive exchange of buffers).

note: I wrote about the difference between a Queue and SimpleQueue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62818757/13782669)

```
Sync SimpleQueue:  1.4309470653533936
AioSimpleQueue:  12.32670259475708
AioQueue:  14.342737436294556
AioPipe:  11.747064590454102
subprocess pipe stream:  7.344956159591675
socket stream:  4.360717058181763
```

```
# main.py
import sys
import time
import asyncio
import aioprocessing as ap
import multiprocessing as mp
import proc

count = 5*10**4
data = b'*'*100


async def sync_simple_queue_func():
    out_ = mp.SimpleQueue()
    in_ = mp.SimpleQueue()
    p = ap.AioProcess(target=proc.start_sync_queue_func, args=(out_, in_))
    p.start()

    begin_ts = time.time()
    for i in range(count):
        out_.put(data)
        res = in_.get()
    print('Sync SimpleQueue: ', time.time() - begin_ts)
    out_.put(None)


async def simple_queue_func():
    out_ = ap.AioSimpleQueue()
    in_ = ap.AioSimpleQueue()
    p = ap.AioProcess(target=proc.start_queue_func, args=(out_, in_))
    p.start()

    begin_ts = time.time()
    for i in range(count):
        await out_.coro_put(data)
        res = await in_.coro_get()
    print('AioSimpleQueue: ', time.time() - begin_ts)
    await out_.coro_put(None)


async def queue_func():
    out_ = ap.AioQueue()
    in_ = ap.AioQueue()
    p = ap.AioProcess(target=proc.start_queue_func, args=(out_, in_))
    p.start()
    begin_ts = time.time()
    for i in range(count):
        await out_.coro_put(data)
        res = await in_.coro_get()
    print('AioQueue: ', time.time() - begin_ts)
    await out_.coro_put(None)


async def pipe_func():
    main_, child_ = ap.AioPipe()
    p = ap.AioProcess(target=proc.start_pipe_func, args=(child_,))
    p.start()
    begin_ts = time.time()
    for i in range(count):
        await main_.coro_send(data)
        res = await main_.coro_recv()
    print('AioPipe: ', time.time() - begin_ts)
    await main_.coro_send(None)
    await p.coro_join()


server = None
async def handle_child(reader, writer):
    begin_ts = time.time()
    for i in range(count):
        writer.write(data)
        res = await reader.read(len(data))
    print('socket stream: ', time.time() - begin_ts)
    writer.close()


async def socket_func():
    global server
    addr = ('127.0.0.1', 8888)
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_child, *addr)
    p = ap.AioProcess(target=proc.start_socket_func, args=(addr,))
    p.start()
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

async def subprocess_func():
    prog = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        'python proc.py',
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    begin_ts = time.time()
    for i in range(count):
        prog.stdin.write(data)
        res = await prog.stdout.read(len(data))
    print('subprocess pipe stream: ', time.time() - begin_ts)
    prog.stdin.close()


async def main():
    await sync_simple_queue_func()
    await simple_queue_func()
    await queue_func()
    await pipe_func()
    await subprocess_func()
    await socket_func()


asyncio.run(main())
```

```
# proc.py

import asyncio
import sys

import aioprocessing as ap


async def sync_queue_func(in_, out_):
    while True:
        n = in_.get()
        if n is None:
            return
        out_.put(n)


async def queue_func(in_, out_):
    while True:
        n = await in_.coro_get()
        if n is None:
            return
        await out_.coro_put(n)

async def pipe_func(child):
    while True:
        n = await child.coro_recv()
        if n is None:
            return
        await child.coro_send(n)

data = b'*' * 100

async def socket_func(addr):

    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(*addr)
    while True:
        n = await reader.read(len(data))
        if not n:
            break
        writer.write(n)


def start_sync_queue_func(in_, out_):
    asyncio.run(sync_queue_func(in_, out_))

def start_queue_func(in_, out_):
    asyncio.run(queue_func(in_, out_))


def start_pipe_func(child):
    asyncio.run(pipe_func(child))


def start_socket_func(addr):
    asyncio.run(socket_func(addr))


async def connect_stdin_stdout():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
    protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader)
    dummy = asyncio.Protocol()
    await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: protocol, sys.stdin)  # sets read_transport
    w_transport, _ = await loop.connect_write_pipe(lambda: dummy, sys.stdout)
    writer = asyncio.StreamWriter(w_transport, protocol, reader, loop)
    return reader, writer


async def main():
    reader, writer = await connect_stdin_stdout()
    while True:
        res = await reader.read(len(data))
        if not res:
            break
        writer.write(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```